# Microsoft SQL Pivot Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to pivot some data an just cant get it. My data looks like this:

```
ID          Total Due
3065765     145.78  
3065765     22.58   
3065765     57.92
```

I am trying to get one row of

```
Id,     total due
3065765 145.78 22.58 57.92
```

Comment: this has got to be the most snobbish forum out there. people will leave snide comments and be quick to edit but slow to help.

Comment: Marc's comment it **not** a "snide comment". It's a valid question because there is a huge different between Microsoft SQL Server and Microsoft Access in what they can do.

Comment: of course there is. I apologize. I must have taken the multiple ???? and exclamation point out of context. Common sense aint so common

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `STUFF` function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx

```
 SELECT [ID]
    , STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CONVERT(varchar(30),A.[Total Due]) FROM mytable A
    Where A.[ID]=B.[ID] FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') As [Total Due] 
    From mytable B
    Group By [ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically with a SQL Pivot, you have a type column or something you can pivot on, like a price type or other category to use as the column headers for your prices.  Take a look here for the syntax for Pivot.  Perhaps you could use ROW_Number() to get a number column for row for a given ID.  Then use that as your pivot (For) column.  Here's a link to a similar example.  http://www.bimonkey.com/2011/05/ranking-and-numbering-rows-and-subsets-of-rows-in-t-sql/